# Spring security configuration is not filtering secured access

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm exporting a set of REST webservices that are protected using HTTP BASIC. My spring configuration used to work well, but I discovered recently that it is not working at all, because it is providing access to some webservices without providing any user/password. Looking to the logs I can see the following :

```
2015-04-10 16:26:58,811 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,811 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:  140 - No HttpSession currently exists
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:   91 - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,812 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:  102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG SessionManagementFilter:   92 - Requested session ID 35A9CBAD338A61BA5D0B7A5D1D821628 is invalid.
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:  337 - /statefull/f/search/hostname/DESKTOP-OMAR/deviceId/65536?format=json at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-04-10 16:26:58,813 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:  185 - Public object - authentication not attempted
```

The URL provided is considered as "public object" for some unknown reason.
My configuration is the following:

```
<s:global-method-security 
        secured-annotations="enabled" 
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<s:http use-expressions="true" realm="My Webservice" create-session="ifRequired">
    <s:http-basic />
    <s:intercept-url pattern='/**'/>
</s:http>
```

Does anyone see what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `access` attribute (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

*I would expect that spring would complain about the wrong configuration, so maybe the configuration file is not taken in account at all (or I`am wrong)*

Comment: Seems your answer is right, and my code is wrong since a long time... Thanks